# reportlab python add specific image background per page

Tags: pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to draw an image background on every page by specifying which background for which page. Giving a list of `PIL` images to the `canvasmaker` when `build` pages happen seems to be right but the trouble comes when to know about the page count.
For example, if I want to create a long table spanning across several pages and another one after that, how to tell at which page to change the image background?

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate,Table,Image as reportlab_Image

page_format = A4
units = cm
stream = BytesIO()
bottom_margin = top_margin = right_margin = left_margin = 1
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(stream,
                        pagesize = page_format,
                        bottomMargin = bottom_margin * units,
                        topMargin = top_margin * units,
                        rightMargin = right_margin * units,
                        leftMargin = left_margin * units
                        )
pages = [] # pages to build
backgrounds = [] # image backgrounds to draw on canvas per page

# create some content for pages. code shortened for brevity
table_1 = Table(…)
background_1 = reportlab_Image(SOME_PIL_IMAGE)
pages.append(table_1)
backgrounds.append(background_1)

table_2 = Table(…)
pages.append(table_2)
background_2 = reportlab_Image(SOME_OTHER_PIL_IMAGE)
backgrounds.append(background_2)

doc.build(pages, canvasmaker = BackgroundCanvas) # where BackgroundCanvas would be a class receiving backgrounds as arguments
```